# Check modifierFlags of NSEvent if a certain modifier was pressed but no other

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, event-listener, nsevent, modifier-key

I just experimented with the `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` method in NSEvent and came across the following question: How do I find out if ***only*** certain modifiers were pressed?

A short example to set this question into context: I wanted to listen for the shortcut "⌘+W". Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *theEvent) {
    if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask && [theEvent keyCode] == 13) {
        [self.window performClose:self];
    }
    return theEvent;
}];
```

This works well, however the shortcut will be triggered, even if more modifier keys are pressed, e.g. "⌃+⌘+W" or "⇧+⌃+⌥+⌘+W". Is there a way to circumvent this?

A simple solution would be to check for all other modifier keys and ensure they are not pressed. This seems tedious and error prone - besides it's ugly enough as it is now with the unary "&". In addition you may get into trouble if (for some reason) another modifier key is added to keyboard layouts.

As always I'm thankful for any recommendations.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think this'll do it:

```
// Mask out everything but the key flags
NSUInteger flags = [theEvent modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagDeviceIndependentFlagsMask;
if( flags == NSCommandKeyMask ){
    // Got it!
}
```

Hat tip to SpaceDog [for pointing out the deprecation of the original mask name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482334/603977), `NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask`.

Comment: Wow, that's neat! Now I have to use the unary "&" just once and finally understood what the `NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask` is for: The modifierFlags normally are set to 256 by default and other flags are added to it, this way I clean up so only the pressed keys are represented by the `modifierFlags` value. This way it's possible to write combinations of modifier keys like in Carbon, e.g. `flags == NSCommandKeyMask + NSControlKeyMas` if ⌘ **and** ⌃ should be pressed rather writing `flags & NSCommandKeyMask && flags & NSControlKeyMask`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pedantic mode dictates that masks should only be (bitwise) OR'd ('|'). Otherwise carry bits will come back to bite you.

Comment: `[theEvent modifierFlags] & (NSControlKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask)` can be used for multiples

Comment: unfortunately, thanks to Apple, NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask is deprecated. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 5 version**

```
if event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) == .command {
    // Got it!
}
```

Answer (score 6):

@JoshCaswell answer has been outdated thanks to Apple, because `NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask` has been deprecated since 10.12.

His answer updated to the new syntax is

```
// Mask out everything but the key flags
NSUInteger flags = [theEvent modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagDeviceIndependentFlagsMask;
if( flags == NSCommandKeyMask ){
  // Got it!
}
```

`NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask` has been replaced with `NSEventModifierFlagDeviceIndependentFlagsMask` because it makes a world of difference...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe even better...

```
if event.modifierFlags.contains(.shift){
    // do it
}
```