# NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: Hotkey Intercepting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, hotkeys, nsevent

I wanna intercept hotkeys that begin with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and ends with a character (mandatory).
I have the following code:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSFlagsChangedMask handler: ^(NSEvent *event) {
    NSUInteger flags = [event modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask;
    if(flags == NSControlKeyMask + NSShiftKeyMask){
        NSLog(@"pressed!");
    }
}];
```

What do i need to add to my code to check if the user pressed <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+character, and what character the user pressed?

The code `NSLog(@"pressed!");` will be executed only if what i said above is true.
This is my pseudo-code for what i'm looking for:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSFlagsChangedMask handler: ^(NSEvent *event) {
    NSUInteger flags = [event modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask;
    if((flags == NSControlKeyMask + NSShiftKeyMask) && [event containsCharacter]){
       NSLog(@"%@", [event character];
    }
}];
```

So if the user presses <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+1 i'll do one thing, if <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+2 other thing, and so on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check modifierFlags of NSEvent if a certain modifier was pressed but no other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084266/check-modifierflags-of-nsevent-if-a-certain-modifier-was-pressed-but-no-other)

Comment: It's a bitmask. Check it like any other.

Comment: can you please answer the question with example code for what i've asked so i can accept your answer, please?

Comment: I'm not going to repost the answer from that question. If the link that I provided has answered your question, then click the "flag" link and write a message indicating that. Otherwise, make it clearer what you're asking and how it differs from the link I've provided.

Comment: i just want to know if the event was triggered by ctrl-shift and a normal character. for example, take a look at this pseudo-code (based on what i wrote above): `if((flags == NSControlKeyMask + NSShiftKeyMask) && [event containsCharacter]){ NSLog(@"%@", [event character];}` understand?

Comment: In order to capture global keystrokes, you will also need to enable access for assistive devices in the Accessibility menu of system preferences..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare bitwise:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent { 
    if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & (NSControlKeyMask | NSShiftKeyMask)) { 
        if (theEvent.keyCode == 1/* add the right key code */) {
            NSLog(@"Do something");
        }
    } else { 
        [super keyDown:theEvent]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: hai @Pedro Viera, can you tell me where to call this keyDown: method?

Comment: @R. Dewi, just use this on `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` - `[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler: ^(NSEvent *event) {
        NSUInteger flags = [event modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask;
        if (flags == NSControlKeyMask + NSShiftKeyMask) {
          //code if user presses ctrl+shift
        }
    }]; `

Comment: thank you for the answer @PedroVieira , can i do something like this for iPad bluetooth keyboard?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
 [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
    NSUInteger key = 8; // 8 is "C"
    NSUInteger modifier = NSControlKeyMask + NSShiftKeyMask; 
    if ([event keyCode] == key && [NSEvent modifierFlags] == modifier)

NSLog(@"pressed!");

}];
```

Comment: This is not how you check bitmasks. There are extra flags in `modifierFlags` that will ensure that it is never `==` your `modifier`.