# How to detect user tap on iPad Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: ios5, bluetooth, uitextfield, uitextview, keyboard-events

I use a bluetooth keyboard to connect into my app in iPad. I use it to type on UITextView or UITextField. And now I need to detect if user tap Command + Z button from that bluetooth keyboard. Is that any event of notification to get detect this? I have read this [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: Hotkey Intercepting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379961/nsevent-addglobalmonitorforeventsmatchingmask-hotkey-intercepting) it use `NSEvent` , but I dont think I can use it in iPad app. Can somebody point me what i have to do?

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you got any proper solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

excellent question - i was having this huge problem in my recent project. There are two methods which will respond differently when you use a bluetooth keyboard and inbuilt keyboard - uikeyboardwillshownotification and uikeybaordwillhidenotification. Keep some nslogs inside these methods and see the response. The other way is to see the framesize of keyboard when your textfield begins editing - textfielddidbeginediting - try seeing the frame of the keyboard - bluetooth will have height zero - using that you can sort out your issue

Comment: if you have to just realize tapping of cmd + z key - then there is a textfield delegate method - textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: - here there is a string arguement - all the current charaters you type is   this string - so you can do caseinsensitivecompare - with respect to this string and any character - z or cmd key and put your validations correspondingly

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you give me a sample code to do caseinsensitivecompare?

Comment: This is the code where i compare a annotation title with current location - ([annotation.title caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Current Location"] == NSOrderedSame)

Comment: This is the delegate method for single character checking. Here i dont allow user to enter "#". Similarly you can put in CMD or z. For alphabets - caseinsensitivecompare:                                 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    
    
        if([string isEqualToString:@"#"]  )
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else
            return YES;
    
    
}

Comment: hi @Ashwin i have try your suggestion, but i use UITextview, so i try it in uitextviewdelegate..when i press CMD + z, it never called -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

but it always called -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView, can you give me another suggestion?

Comment: Make sure you have added uitextviewdelegate and set it as well.
And the delegate method is 
             - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView  
            shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText: 
(NSString *)text

Comment: yes i have set it right, but i have typo on my last comment :)

Comment: So u mean you have set the delgate and used the specified delegate method and still have the issue? If so upload the code of the delegate method